# Can I calculate a transformation matrix given a set of points?

Tags: matrix, transformation, linear-algebra

I'm trying to deduct the 2D-transformation parameters from the result.

Given is a large number of samples in an unknown X-Y-coordinate system as well as their respective counterparts in WGS84 (longitude, latitude). Since the area is small, we can assume the target system to be flat, too.

Sadly I don't know which order of scale, rotate, translate was used, and I'm not even sure if there were 1 or 2 translations.

I tried to create a lengthy equation system, but that ended up too complex for me to handle. Basic geometry also failed me, as the order of transformations is unknown and I would have to check every possible combination order.

Is there a systematic approach to this problem?

Comment: Do you know which point in X-Y corresponds to which point in WGS84?

Comment: Yes I know which ones correspond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figuring out the scaling factor is easy, just choose any two points and find the distance between them in your X-Y space and your WGS84 space and the ratio of them is your scaling factor.

The rotations and translations is a little trickier, but not nearly as difficult when you learn that the result of applying any number of rotations or translations (in 2 dimensions only!) can be reduced to a single rotation about some unknown point by some unknown angle.

Suddenly you have N points to determine 3 unknowns, the axis of rotation (x and y coordinate) and the angle of rotation.

Calculating the rotation looks like this:

```
    Pr = R*(Pxy - Paxis_xy) + Paxis_xy
```

`Pr` is your rotated point in X-Y space which then needs to be converted to WGS84 space (if the axes of your coordinate systems are different).
`R` is the familiar [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) depending on your rotation angle.
`Pxy` is your unrotated point in X-Y space.
`Paxis_xy` is the axis of rotation in X-Y space.

To actually find the 3 unknowns, you need to un-scale your WGS84 points (or equivalently scale your X-Y points) by the scaling factor you found and shift your points so that the two coordinate systems have the same origin.

First, finding the angle of rotation: take two corresponding pairs of points `P1, P1'` and `P2, P2'` and write out

```
     P1' = R(P1-A) + A
     P2' = R(P2-A) + A
```

where I swapped `A = Paxis_xy` for brevity.  Subtracting the two equations gives:

```
     P2'-P1' = R(P2-P1)
     B = R * C
     Bx = cos(a) * Cx - sin(a) * Cy
     By = cos(a) * Cx + sin(a) * Cy
     By + Bx = 2 * cos(a) * Cx
     (By + Bx) / (2 * Cx) = cos(a)
     ...
     (By - Bx) / (2 * Cy) = sin(a)
     a = atan2(sin(a), cos(a)) <-- to get the right quadrant
```

And you have your angle, you can also do a quick check that `cos(a) * cos(a) + sin(a) * sin(a) == 1` to make sure either you got all the calculations correct or that your system really is an orientation-preserving isometry (consists only of translations and rotations).

Now that we know `a` we know `R` and so to find `A` we do:

```
    P1` = R(P1-A) + A
    P1' - R*P1 = (I-R)A
    A = (inverse(I-R)) * (P1' - R*P1)
```

where the [inversion of a 2x2 matrix is easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices).

**EDIT**: There is an error in the above, or more specifically one case that needs to be treated separately.
There is one combination of translations and rotations that does not reduce to a single rotation and that is a single translation.  You can think of it in terms of fixed points (how many points are unchanged after the operation).
A translation has no fixed points (all points are changed) and a rotation has 1 fixed point (the axis doesn't change).  It turns out that two rotations leave 1 fixed point and a translation and a rotation leaves 1 fixed point, which (with a little proof that says the number of fixed points tells you the operation performed) is the reason that arbitrary combinations of these result in a single rotation.

What this means for you is that if your angle comes out as `0` then using the method above will give you `A = 0` as well, which is likely incorrect.  In this case you have to do `A = P1' - P1`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. One question: I'm not sure if I understand, why is the original order of operations not important when calculating the scaling?

Comment: @mafu rotations and translations are isometric, meaning that they preserve distances between points.  Thus the only thing that affects the distance between points is the scaling factor.  If two points are a distance 1 apart and they get translated, they're still a distance of 1 apart.  If they scaled afterwards they're a distance of k apart and if they're rotated after that they're still a distance of k apart.

Comment: Ah, so since there was only 1 operation that changed distances, thus the distance change must be effected by the scaling and nothing else. Thanks!

Comment: @mafu even more than that, since there's only one _type_ of operation (scaling) here that can change relative distances and since multiple scalings can be expressed as one scaling, you only have to find one scaling and not worry about whether there are more or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you have *n* points (X<sub>1</sub>,Y<sub>1</sub>),...,(X<sub>n</sub>,Y<sub>n</sub>), the corresponding points, say, (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>),...,(x<sub>n</sub>,y<sub>n</sub>) in another coordinate system, and the former are supposedly obtained from the latter by rotation, scaling and translation.

Note that this data does not determine the fixed point of rotation / scaling, or the order in which the operations "should" be applied. On the other hand, if you know these beforehand or choose them arbitrarily, you will find a rotation, translation and scaling factor that transform the data as supposed to.

For example, you can pick an any point, say, p<sub>0</sub> = [X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup> (column vector) as the fixed point of rotation & scaling and subtract its coordinates from those of two other points to get p<sub>2</sub> = [X<sub>2</sub>-X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>2</sub>-Y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, and p<sub>3</sub> = [X<sub>3</sub>-X<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>3</sub>-Y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup>. Also take the column vectors q<sub>2</sub> = [x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, q<sub>3</sub> = [x<sub>3</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup>. Now [p<sub>2</sub> p<sub>3</sub>] = A*[q<sub>2</sub> q<sub>3</sub>], where A is an unknwon 2x2 matrix representing the roto-scaling. You can solve it (unless you were unlucky and chose degenerate points) as A = [p<sub>2</sub> p<sub>3</sub>] * [q<sub>2</sub> q<sub>3</sub>]<sup>-1</sup> where <sup>-1</sup> denotes matrix inverse (of the 2x2 matrix [q<sub>2</sub> q<sub>3</sub>]). Now, if the transformation between the coordinate systems really is a roto-scaling-translation, all the points should satisfy P<sub>k</sub> = A * (Q<sub>k</sub>-q<sub>0</sub>) + p<sub>0</sub>, where P<sub>k</sub> = [X<sub>k</sub>, Y<sub>k</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, Q<sub>k</sub> = [x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, q<sub>0</sub>=[x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, and k=1,..,n.

If you want, you can quite easily determine the scaling and rotation parameter from the components of A or combine b = -A * q<sub>0</sub> + p<sub>0</sub> to get P<sub>k</sub> = A*Q<sub>k</sub> + b.

The above method does not react well to noise or choosing degenerate points. If necessary, this can be fixed by applying, e.g., Principal Component Analysis, which is also just a few lines of code if MATLAB or some other linear algebra tools are available.

Comment: Luckily the data are without noise. I'll read up on how to apply this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Assuming this is an affine transformation matrix. You need 3 ordered points which correspond to 3 different other ordered points you can calculate the transformation matrix.

First use the following equation which gives us the matrix that maps `(0,0), (0,1) and (1,0)` to your three ordered points `(x1, y1), (x2,y2), and (x4,y4)` which is:

```
Matrix(
   a = x4 - x1,
   b = x2 - x1,
   c = x1,
   d = y4 - y1,
   e = y2 - y1,
   f = y1,
)
```

This gives us the matrix that will map `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)` to your points `a1, a2, a4`.

We then calculate the same thing for the other matrix for points `b1, b2, b4`.

Now we have two matrices that will convert our points the same points. We'll call these matrix `T` and `R`. If we want to map the points from one to the other it's simply `M = T * ~R` where we do regular matrix multiplication and `~` tell us to invert that matrix. So we go from points:

`a1, a2, a4` --(via T)--> `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)` --(via ~R)--> `b1, b2, b4.`

Giving us our matrix M by doing `T * ~R`

We have M such that:

`a1, a2, a4` --(via M)--> `b1, b2, b4.`

---

If you, for example, have 4 points that map to 4 other points the math gets harder.

Mapping the points `(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)`

```py
        i = 1
        try:
            j = (y1 - y2 + y3 - y4) / (y2 - y3)
            k = (x1 - x2 + x3 - x4) / (x4 - x3)
            m = (y4 - y3) / (y2 - y3)
            n = (x2 - x3) / (x4 - x3)

            h = i * (j - k * m) / (1 - m * n)
            g = i * (k - j * n) / (1 - m * n)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            h = 0.0
            g = 0.0

        c = x1 * i
        f = y1 * i
        a = x4 * (g + i) - x1 * i
        b = x2 * (h + i) - x1 * i
        d = y4 * (g + i) - y1 * i
        e = y2 * (h + i) - y1 * i
```

If the matrix is affine your values for `g` and `h` are 0. But, it otherwise causes a divide by 0 error here. `i` is given for completeness and should probably be set to 1 and removed. It only scales your values for for the 9x9 matrix. The difference here is that perspective/warps need 3x3 matrices (and lines that were parallel before can now have intersections). If you want to somehow use the 4th point (`p3`) as a sanity check:

This would be mapped to the point p3 would be mapped to (1,1).

```
x3 = x4 - x1 + x2
y3 = y4 - y1 + y2
```

If those equations are true then your p3 value is located where it is required to be for the matrix to be affine, if it's not located there the above math would give you the matrix to still make it located at your 4th point.